# Restrict access to admin but allow admin_post hook

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, actions

I'm using this hook to allow only admin roles access dashboard

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/meu-perfil') );
        exit();
    }
});
```

Now I need to run a function when a form is submitted on front end, like so:

```
function editUser() {
    error_log('message');
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'editUser' );
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'editUser' );
```

But the first hook is blocking the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to modify your method of restricting users.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    if ( (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) || ( strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'admin-post.php') ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/meu-perfil') );
        exit();
    }
}
```